# How to model the likelihood of multiple binary outcomes occurring after an event?

Tags: survival, binary-data, time-varying-covariate, recurrent-events

Wanting to know if 3-5 binary outcomes are more likely to occur after an event. For example, are people who experience the event more likely to experience an outcome (within a year or 6 months, etc.) than people who do not experience the event? What kind of model would help me answer this question?

One option that occurred to me is a survival model for each outcome in which $t_0$ (i.e., first timepoint) for each row is the event time. However, I'm not sure how to incorporate people who never experienced an event into that, and people with multiple events would get multiple rows with duplicated outcome data. An alternative is to use the event as the binary DV in a survival model and use the outcomes as time-dependent covariates. However, the DV would occur *before* the IVs in this design, and it seems to require artificial bins for the IVs (e.g., $IV_1$ = whether outcome 1 happened within a year after the event/DV).

Here's some example data. I'm coding this in R. Any advice is much appreciated!

````r
set.seed(311)
library(dplyr)

sample_date <- function(n){
  sample(seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), 
             as.Date("2021-12-31"), 
             by = "day"), n)
}

# Each row represents an event that happened to someone
events <- tibble(
  id = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE),
  event_date = sample_date(10),
  event_type = sample(letters[1:5], 10, replace = T))
events
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>       id event_date event_type
#>    <int> <date>     <chr>     
#>  1     3 2020-03-03 b         
#>  2    10 2020-02-27 b         
#>  3     5 2020-04-02 a         
#>  4     5 2020-07-07 e         
#>  5     5 2020-06-25 c         
#>  6     7 2020-12-16 b         
#>  7    10 2020-03-29 e         
#>  8     4 2020-07-24 a         
#>  9     1 2021-12-06 e         
#> 10     7 2021-03-27 a

# One row per person, regardless of event status
potential_outcomes <- tibble(
  id = 1:10,
  outcome_1 = runif(10) > .8,
  outcome_1_date = if_else(outcome_1, sample_date(10), as.Date(NA)),
  outcome_2 = runif(10) > .4,
  outcome_2_date = if_else(outcome_2, sample_date(10), as.Date(NA))
)
potential_outcomes
#> # A tibble: 10 × 5
#>       id outcome_1 outcome_1_date outcome_2 outcome_2_date
#>    <int> <lgl>     <date>         <lgl>     <date>        
#>  1     1 FALSE     NA             TRUE      2021-08-26    
#>  2     2 FALSE     NA             TRUE      2021-08-16    
#>  3     3 FALSE     NA             FALSE     NA            
#>  4     4 FALSE     NA             TRUE      2020-12-14    
#>  5     5 TRUE      2021-12-13     TRUE      2021-05-03    
#>  6     6 FALSE     NA             TRUE      2020-06-11    
#>  7     7 FALSE     NA             TRUE      2020-05-23    
#>  8     8 FALSE     NA             TRUE      2021-09-22    
#>  9     9 TRUE      2020-04-14     FALSE     NA            
#> 10    10 FALSE     NA             TRUE      2020-11-18
```
````